# Time zero for a switch target trial

Tags: r, inference, causality, clinical-trials

One of the most difficult aspects in target trial emulation in my opinion is the time zero specification.

Let's say I am interested in emulating a hypothetical target trial in which patients who fulfill eligibility criteria either switch to a new treatment (group B) or remain on their previous treatment (group A) as in the figure below.

[image: Study Design]

[Hernan and colleagues](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4832051/) argue that you could either use one time point (first after eligibility or a random date) or use all eligibility times and emulate multiple nested target trial.

For the first possibility, if we take the first eligibility time point or a random one, many patients will switch to group B at a later time point or may have switched already for quite some time and therefore treatment assignment will not be correct (or inefficient). I thought of taking all time points of individuals who switched to group B and assign a random time point to group A as eligibility time point. However, this might introduce bias as I am looking in the future. Does anyone have a good idea how to approach that problem?

Alternatively, one could estimate multiple nested trials at each time point. Does anyone have sample code to demonstrate the approach? I have read the article by [García-Albéniz and colleagues](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5759953/) but I would require more guidance.

UPDATE:
I have found a great paper from [García-Albéniz and colleagues](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5417337/) which describes the process of estimating mutliple nested trials at several time points in the technical appendix. They use a dataset to estimate the impact of screening colonoscopy on the detection of colon cancer.

I replicated the sample dataset here.

```r
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(ipw)


# Replicate sample data from Garcia-Albeniz et al.
df <- tibble::tribble(
   ~id, ~trial,             ~arm, ~fup_start, ~fup_end, ~cancer, ~covariate,
  "02",     0L, "No Colonoscopy",         0L,       9L,      0L,         1L,
  "03",     0L,    "Colonoscopy",         0L,       1L,      1L,         0L,
  "06",     0L, "No Colonoscopy",         0L,       6L,      0L,         1L,
  "02",     1L, "No Colonoscopy",         1L,       9L,      0L,         1L,
  "05",     1L, "No Colonoscopy",         1L,       5L,      1L,         0L,
  "06",     1L, "No Colonoscopy",         1L,       6L,      0L,         1L,
  "01",     2L, "No Colonoscopy",         2L,       4L,      0L,         2L,
  "05",     2L, "No Colonoscopy",         2L,       5L,      1L,         0L,
  "06",     2L, "No Colonoscopy",         2L,       6L,      0L,         1L,
  "01",     3L, "No Colonoscopy",         3L,       4L,      0L,         2L,
  "05",     3L, "No Colonoscopy",         3L,       5L,      1L,         0L,
  "06",     3L, "No Colonoscopy",         3L,       6L,      0L,         1L,
  "04",     4L, "No Colonoscopy",         4L,       6L,      1L,         1L,
  "05",     4L,    "Colonoscopy",         4L,       5L,      1L,         0L,
  "06",     4L, "No Colonoscopy",         4L,       6L,      0L,         2L,
  "07",     4L, "No Colonoscopy",         4L,       9L,      0L,         0L,
  "04",     5L, "No Colonoscopy",         5L,       6L,      1L,         2L,
  "06",     5L, "No Colonoscopy",         5L,       6L,      0L,         2L,
  "07",     5L, "No Colonoscopy",         5L,       9L,      0L,         0L,
  "06",     6L, "No Colonoscopy",         6L,       6L,      0L,         2L,
  "07",     6L, "No Colonoscopy",         6L,       9L,      0L,         0L,
  "07",     7L, "No Colonoscopy",         7L,       9L,      0L,         1L,
  "07",     8L, "No Colonoscopy",         8L,       9L,      0L,         1L,
  "07",     9L, "No Colonoscopy",         9L,       9L,      0L,         2L
  )
```

I then go on and calculate ipw-weights for the baseline covariate in the example (gives a warning but I will proceed for illustration purposes):

```r
# This is needed to calculate weights
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(arm_cat = as.numeric(arm == "Colonoscopy"))

# Calculate weights using the ipw package
weights <- ipwpoint(exposure = arm_cat, 
         family = "binomial", 
         link = "logit", 
         denominator = ~covariate, 
         data = as.data.frame(df))
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Now I think I can go on and run the Cox-regression model with the ipw-weights:

```r
coxph(Surv(fup_start, fup_end, cancer) ~ arm + cluster(id),
      data = df, weights = weights$ipw.weights)
#> Warning in Surv(fup_start, fup_end, cancer): Stop time must be > start time, NA
#> created
#> Call:
#> coxph(formula = Surv(fup_start, fup_end, cancer) ~ arm, data = df, 
#>     weights = weights$ipw.weights, cluster = id)
#> 
#>                      coef exp(coef) se(coef) robust se      z      p
#> armNo Colonoscopy -1.8247    0.1613   0.6776    0.9718 -1.878 0.0604
#> 
#> Likelihood ratio test=7.44  on 1 df, p=0.006373
#> n= 22, number of events= 7 
#>    (2 Beobachtungen als fehlend gelöscht)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

My remaining questions:
Is this a valid way to do the analysis? Are standard errors already correct if I use `cluster(id)` or do we need to do something else to account for the multiple occurences of patients in the dataset? Authors suggest bootstrapping, how would one do this here exactly?

UPDATE 2:
I guess I can use simple bootstrapping using the `boot` package where I repeat the whole process of calculating weights and estimating a cox-regression.

```r
library(boot)
boot_function <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- df[indices, ]
  wt <- ipwpoint(exposure = arm_cat, 
                 family = "binomial", 
                 link = "logit", 
                 denominator = ~covariate, 
                 data = as.data.frame(d))
  wt$ipw.weights[1]
  obj <- coxph(Surv(fup_start, fup_end, cancer) ~ arm, data = d,
           weights = wt$ipw.weights)
  coefs <- summary(obj)$coefficients
  coefs[, "coef"]
} 

# I use a low R here because the "arm" variable contains a low
# number of colonoscopies and therefore often data is sampled 
# without any patients receiving colonoscopy. 

b <- boot(df, boot_function, R = 20) 
  
# I use quantiles to calculate 95% CI. I had to add na.rm = TRUE
# because the toy-data I am using is not quite small and therefore 
# not so good for demonstration purposes

quantile(b$t, probs = c(0.025, 0.975), na.rm = TRUE)
#>       2.5%      97.5% 
#> -19.659656  -1.046503
```

I am happy for any inputs on this approach. Many thanks!